# Tooltip number formatting in google chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

How can I format number in a tooltip in google chart? I tried to apply `"none"` formatting in datatable and also applied `"####"` formatting on h-axis in google chart option but still can see 2,012 in tooltip.

```
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            [
            {label: "year", type: "number", format: "none"},
            {label: "performance", type: "number", format: "none"},
        ],
        ["2009", 10],
        ["2010", 15],
        ["2011", 3],
        ["2012", 5]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}, format: "####"},
      vAxis: {minValue: 0}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

JSFiddle can be found here:
https://jsfiddle.net/ux37j0dk/3/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

by default, the tooltip will display the formatted value of data table cell

you can use the [NumberFormat](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformat) class to format the data table...

```
  var yearPattern = "0";
  var formatNumber = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: yearPattern
  });
  formatNumber.format(data, 0);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    [{
        label: "year",
        type: "number",
        format: "none"
      },
      {
        label: "performance",
        type: "number",
        format: "none"
      },
    ],
    ["2009", 10],
    ["2010", 15],
    ["2011", 3],
    ["2012", 5]
  ]);
  
  var yearPattern = "0";
  var formatNumber = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: yearPattern
  });
  formatNumber.format(data, 0);

  var options = {
    title: 'Company Performance',
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Year',
      titleTextStyle: {
        color: '#333'
      },
      format: yearPattern
    },
    vAxis: {
      minValue: 0
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

you can also use object notation to supply both the value (`v:`) and the formatted value (`f:`),
when loading the data table...

```
[{v: "2009", f: "2009"}, 10],
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    [{
        label: "year",
        type: "number",
        format: "none"
      },
      {
        label: "performance",
        type: "number",
        format: "none"
      },
    ],
    [{v: "2009", f: "2009"}, 10],
    [{v: "2010", f: "2010"}, 15],
    [{v: "2011", f: "2011"}, 3],
    [{v: "2012", f: "2012"}, 5]
  ]);
  
  var yearPattern = "0";

  var options = {
    title: 'Company Performance',
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Year',
      titleTextStyle: {
        color: '#333'
      },
      format: yearPattern
    },
    vAxis: {
      minValue: 0
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks it works. Just one question how to use this on DataView class? I mean first solution with google.visualization.NumberFormat

Comment: formatter doesn't work on data veiws, apply before creating the view, or convert the view back to a data table --> `view = view.toDataTable();` -- then use the formatter...